How to set up HA for Metricbeat + Filebeat + Logstash on our log forwarders?
I am looking for a solution to implement HA on our log forwarders.
Our log forwards run Filebeat + Logstash + Metricbeat. The forwarder is a Linux box with these services running. The services connect back to an Elastic instance.
I want to implement HA for our log forwarders.
By HA I mean some type of high availability, or a backup log forwarder.
I was thinking of setting up another Linux box with the same services running and connecting back to the same Elastic instance.
The problem is I am not sure doing this is a good idea, I am not sure if this will double up the logs in Elastic.
What is the supported proper way to set up HA for our log forwarders?
I am curious if this can be done in an Active/Active manor, or if an active/passive system needs to be engineered?
I did find this post but its almost a decade old. Is there any new solutions out there?
EDIT: The log forwarders send their data to an Azure Event Hub instance. I am wondering if I can create two log forwarders, and two event hub instances (Each log forwarder has its own event hub instance), and possibly perform HA from Azure Event Hubs?
